# What does the notation $\mathcal{N}(z; \mu, \sigma)$ stand for in statistics?

Tags: statistics, notation, random-variables, terminology, normal-distribution

I know that the notation $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$ stands for a normal distribution.
But in my book (about Bayesian neural networks) there is this notation:
$$\mathcal{N}(z; \mu, \sigma)$$
**For being exact, it is written $\mathcal{N}(z; 0, I)$.**

I want to ask what does this means.

Picture of the book:
[image: picture of the book An Introduction to Variational Autoencoders]

Comment: $I$ is identity matrix, so it's a vector of rvs

Comment: @Alex OK, But then $N(0,I)$ could be fine. What does that $z$ is telling there?

Comment: Can you give an example of the notation being used in context?

Comment: @TrevorGunn It is done.

Comment: @Peyman without more context, I would guess that it stands for the p.d.f. of the Gaussian random variable. i.e. $p(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}}e^{-\|x\|^2/2}$

Comment: @PaxKivimae Yes it really seems that $z$ is playing no rule here. I don't understand why they put that $z$ in the notation!

Comment: I mean, I would guess that it is playing the role of the value for the p.d.f.

Comment: @PaxKivimae Oh you are right I guess. my bad, thanks.

Comment: This notation is explained in the "Notation and definitions" section of the Appendix in [the source the picture is from](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02691).